# Will F# 3.1 will be available for VS 2013 Express for Web?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, f#, visual-studio-2013

When I installed Visual Studio 2013 Express, my installation of Visual Studio 2012 Express was removed.  But I have not been able to get F# to work in Visual Studio Express 2013.  And the official download page still prompts the visitor to download F# with Visual Studio 2012 Express.

Does anyone know if an update is in the offing, or whether I have to reinstall Visual Studio 2012 Express?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Worst case, the compiler is open source and you can use that.

Comment: Is it possible to add F# to Visual Studio Express 2013 with Visual F# Express Tools? - http://fsharp.org/use/windows/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update**: As [announced today by the Visual F# team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2014/01/22/announcing-visual-f-3-1-1-and-support-for-desktop-express.aspx), F# is now supported in Visual Studio Express Desktop and Web via the [F# Tools 3.1.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41654).

---

***Old answer**: I just asked this to Brian Harry on Neowin.net, he answered: "[F# is not in any of the VS 2013 Express SKUs](http://www.neowin.net/news/interview-we-chat-with-microsofts-brian-harry-about-visual-studio-2013#comment-2410913)". There might be a way to integrate it in one of the express editions but nothing supported out of the box.
Yeah, this sucks. :(*

Comment: Thanks for updating an answer with new, critical information!